# Azure CosmosDB. Continuation token length in stored procedure

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I have a REST API which is intent to query the documents stored in CosmosDB with OData-like syntax. I'm returning documents with chunks. I.e. I'm setting $top=10 and get 10 documents with a continuation token. This continuation token is returned from stored procedure:

```js
var accepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(),
            sql, requestOptions,
            function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
                // ...
                // put responseOptions.continuation into response body
            });
```

The problem is if the continuation token is long (i.e. 6k characters), an I pass it into URL, the URL cannot be handled and I can't reach out my endpoint (getting 404). As far as I understand the more complex initial SQL query is the longer is the continuation token an its length cannot be set up.

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there would be a out of the box solution for this issue. What you can try is to implement tiny url kind of framework at your service layer.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-design-a-tiny-url-or-url-shortener/